# How to accept ANY delegate as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am interested in writing a method that would accept another method as a parameter but do not want to be locked into a specific signature - because I don't care about that. I am only interested whether the method throws an exception when invoked.  Is there a construct in the .NET Framework that will allow me to accept any delegate as a parameter?

For example, all of the following calls should work (without using overloads!):

```
DoesItThrowException(doSomething(arg));
DoesItThrowException(doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5));
DoesItThrowException(doNothing());
```

Comment: How are you testing to see if the method throws an exception? If you're planning on sticking it in a `try`-`catch` block and invoking it, you're still going to have to provide it parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool DoesItThrowException(Action a)
{
  try
  {
    a();
    return false;
  }  
  catch
  {
    return true;
  }
}

DoesItThrowException(delegate { desomething(); });

//or

DoesItThrowException(() => desomething());
```

Answer (score 13):

You can't invoke it unless you give it arguments; and you can't give it arguments unless you know the signature. To get around this, I would place that burden on the caller - I would use `Action` and anon-methods/lambdas, i.e.

```
DoesItThrowException(FirstMethod); // no args, "as is"
DoesItThrowException(() => SecondMethod(arg)); 
DoesItThrowException(() => ThirdMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5));
```

Otherwise, you can use `Delegate` and `DynamicInvoke`, but that is slow and you need to know which args to give it.

```
public static bool DoesItThrowException(Action action) {
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    try {
        action();
        return false;
    } catch {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: With syntax as demonstrated in the question, it's clear that lambda is the only viable choice - he doesn't really want to pass a delegate so much so as a method with all parameters bound.

Comment: @Pavel: You will need a 'better' language for that, like Scheme for instance, that allows syntactic abstraction.

Comment: Why `'better'` and not just `better`? Scheme is really better.

Comment: @SargeBorsch because it is subjective; it does not make sense to say "better" without also saying *at what*. Everything is a trade.